# Create a summary table based on data from another table in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I am new and pretty inexperienced with Power Query, so have struggled with this issue and finding a basic tutorial on Power Query.
I am using Power Pivot to analyse some data. My source data is added to the Excel Data Model using Power Query from an external CSV file.
What I want to be able to do is create a summary table from the source data in a new table. This new table would be added to the data model. My source table (SrcTable) would look like this;

| Order ID | Item Code |
| --- | --- |
| O-001 | I-001 |
| O-001 | I-002 |
| O-002 | I-001 |
| O-003 | I-001 |
| O-003 | I-002 |
| O-003 | I-003 |

My new table would have two columns

- A list of each Item Code
- A Distinct Count of Order ID for each Item Code

So for the example above the SummaryTable would look like this

| Item Code | Num Orders |
| --- | --- |
| I-001 | 3 |
| I-002 | 2 |
| I-003 | 1 |

Can someone please give me some guidance on how can I write a query to create this new table for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your table using data...from table/range... to get it into powerquery

In powerquery

right click the Item Code column and choose Group by...

It should default to doing a count. You can change the name of the column from Count to Num Orders if you want. Then Hit Ok

The do File .. close and load to ... and decide how you want to get the data back into Excel.  There is an optional [x] checkbox to add the data to data model

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does create a table as I needed.

Not directly relevant to this exact question, but if I wanted to create a table that 'imported' more than one column from the source table, how could I do this? I expect a solution with 'M', but I cannot find much documentation. Other than the book 'M is for (Data) Monkey', which I have not read.